# UICollectionView cells keeps reloading when they become visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview which has custom cells, they keep reloading whenever the cells become visible on screen e.g. the collection view has scrolled down and then scrolled back up so that cell is visible again. I want to turn this off and want the cells to only be loaded once and not refresh every single time they are visible. Here is my code for initialising a cell.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  NSLog(@"cell row %d is being refreshed", indexPath.row);
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  LevelCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  Level *levelTemp =[levels objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

  [[cell levelNumber]setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level %@",levelTemp.level]];

  DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];
  obj.totalC=obj.totalC+([levelTemp.comp_questions intValue]);
  obj.totalQ=obj.totalQ+([levelTemp.max_questions intValue]);
  int unlockA = [levelTemp.unlockAmount intValue];

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: No.  No, you don't.  This is exactly how table views and collection views are designed to work.  You only need to keep as many cells in memory as what's on screen... there's a massive performance hit if you try keeping all these cells in memory...

Comment: njgrif is correct, however if you do not care about the performance hit, give each cell a unique cell identifier and it will generate once per cell and not re-use them.

Comment: That's not true actually, @box86rowh  That's actually the worst of both worlds.  It will keep the cells in memory... but it will still reload them just before they're put on screen.

Comment: At the end of the day, a collection view cell is a UI element and only needs to be in memory when it's going to be on screen.  This is an XY problem... there's some other reason that you think you need to keep this in memory... and if you could explain what that reason is, we can help you with what you actually need to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea. The proper way to handle this is to have `levels` store all the needed data, grab the next cell from the the collection view and stuff it with the data from `levels`. It is memory efficient and time efficient.

---

Have an `NSMutableArray` to hold `LevelCell`s. Because the order in which the cell will be requested is not known, you will need to pre-initialize the array. It needs to be the same size as `levels` and value needs need to be `[NSNull null]`.

```
self.cells = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[levels count]];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [levels count]; ++i) {
    self.cells[i] = (id)[NSNull null];
}
```

This can be in your `-viewDidLoad` or maybe as a lazy loaded property.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Look to see if there is a cell at this index
    LevelCell *cell = self.cells[indexPath.item];

    if (cell == (id)[NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"cell row %d is being refreshed", indexPath.item);
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        Level *levelTemp =[levels objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

        [[cell levelNumber]setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level %@",levelTemp.level]];

        DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];
        obj.totalC=obj.totalC+([levelTemp.comp_questions intValue]);
        obj.totalQ=obj.totalQ+([levelTemp.max_questions intValue]);
        int unlockA = [levelTemp.unlockAmount intValue];

        // save the new cell in the array.
        self.cells[indexPath.item] = cell;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Final note: `self.cells` will not be updated when the data is updated. You will need to do that manually. Changes, insertions, and deletions will all need to be mirrored between `levels` and `self.cells`.

Again, this is a bad idea. Really, don't do it.